# How to aplly escape Rules to existing String

Tags: java, string, escaping

so this might be a kind of specific problem.

I have a txt file that I read in line by line and store in an ArrayList.

Here are some lines copied from the txt:

https://pastebin.com/TNqvpvYn

This is how I read the Lines:

```
public static List<String> readFile(String path) {
        BufferedReader br;

        List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                rows.add(line);

                line = br.readLine();
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rows;
    }
```

when I check the length of those Strings using String.length() I get the total size without parts like "\\" being escaped (It should count the size as 1 instead of 2 since \\ is a rule to get \)

So basically I want to check the size of the String after all escape rules have been applied. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you read from a file `\` is escaped as `\\` 
So if your file contains something like `\\` it is encoded as `\\\\`

In a file the length of `\` is 1 and as a String it will also be 1

And when you hava `\\` in a File the length in Java will be 2

Or did I misunderstand you and you want the length of `\\` from a file to return 1

then you could try `line.replace("\\\\", "\\");` to apply the escape rule manually

Comment: Sorry, I think I made it a bit unclear, I actually want two backslashes to return size 1

Comment: you can try to replace two backslashes with only one backslash on every line, by using this `line.replace("\\\\", "\\");`